# passing pyqt object to swig exported c++ code

Tags: c++, pyqt, swig

anyone knows if there exists a method for passing pyQt objects to c++ code?

I'll explain better; say i have this c++ code

```
    void QtGuiPDLVisitor::set_layout(QLayout* _layout){
       layout = _layout;
    }
```

where QtGuiPDLVisitor is a c++ class exported in python using SWIG, so in python i want to do something like this

```
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    visitor = QtGuiPDLVisitor()
    visitor.set_layout(layout)
```

is it possible? The python interpreter says no :(... is there any workaround, like a way of passing pointers or any other hack?

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/picci/workspace/gestface/pypelab/src/pypelab/ui/pipeworkarea.py", line 53, in create_new_computation
    subWindowWidget.setComputation(idx.data())
  File "/home/picci/workspace/gestface/pypelab/src/pypelab/ui/pypeWidgets.py", line 44, in setComputation
    self.widBuilder.buildUi(self)
  File "/home/picci/workspace/gestface/pypelab/src/pypelab/ui/pypeWidgets.py", line 63, in buildUi
    pdlVisitor.set_layout(criteria_area_layout)
  File "/home/picci/workspace/gestface/pipeit/wrap/python/dist/Debug/pipeit.py", line 736, in set_layout
    def set_layout(self, *args) -> "void" : return _pipeit.QtGuiPDLVisitor_set_layout(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'QtGuiPDLVisitor_set_layout', argument 2 of type 'QLayout *'
```

This is the error from python. I already know that this error is due to the fact that Qt4 is wrapper in python using SIP, while i'm using SWIG to wrap, but i think that there must be a way to access directly to the pointer of the Qlayout object and pass it to C++ code from python.

Comment: SWIG should make that exact Python code work. It'll do the pointer conversions for you. You say the Python interpreter gives you an error, so why didn't you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i actually find a way to do that. I used

```
visitor.set_layout_address(sip.unwrapinstance(layout))
```

from python, and than in c++

```
void QtGuiPDLVisitor::set_layout_address(long _layout_address){
    layout = reinterpret_cast<QLayout*>(_layout_address);
}
```

and worked!

here [sip doc](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/python_api.html) for more about sip.unwrapinstance()